# Api error System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 258

Tags: azure, rest

[image: program.cs ConnectionString]
[image: Error screenshot]

I'm currently trying to work through connecting to a cloud-based database with an Api I've found a lot of similar questions but all the fixes I have found on stack haven't worked for my solution any help would be appreciated
[Error that the Api is showing - program.cs ConnectionString ]

ConnectionString in `appsettings`:

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MyContext": 
    "Server=tcp:removed.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=kawamaraedb;Persist Security Info=False;User  ID=Removed;Password='Removed';MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  },
```

ID and Password are correct

My fix

I figured it out i had to manually type in the connection string from azure and take out alot of the added code string

FROM THIS:

Server=tcp:sql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=YOUR DB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={USER};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

TO THIS

"Data Source=tcp:sql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=YOUR DB;User Id={USER};Password={YOUR PASSWORD}"

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to Visual Studio 2022. It seems that the connection string is not correct. For instance, `InitialCatalog` is not a valid key and should be `Initial Catalog`. You may discover more at [Connection String Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: ill look into that now

Comment: it is written as initial catalog in the connection string i shouldve been clear i have been able to access the database via visual studio i can scaffold it into a solution but the api always has a heart attack when i try execute anything

Comment: also the connection string is the one i received from azure